# Can I invoke a function in a new engine scope with Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, java-8, nashorn

Nashorn allows me to evaluate a JavaScript in a new scope, like this:

```
public Object evalInNewScope(String code, Bindings bindings) throws Exception  {
    ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
    context.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    return engine.eval(code, context);
}
```

This is great for thread-safety: The engine instance may be re-used across threads, and each thread can make its own call with thread-specific bindings.

However, I have not found a similar capability for `Invocable#invokeFunction(String, Object...)`.

Does anyone know how I could do what I want? Is there a good reason for this asymmetry?

Comment: Isn't `ENGINE_SCOPE` the default? This is what is mentioned in Example 8 here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html: *The default script context has at least one scope represented by the static field ENGINE_SCOPE.*

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: I want to change the engine scope binding for the invocation of the function, similar to what I can do with eval().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invokeFunction` calls functions only from current context, you cannot provide a context directly.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

ScriptContext ctx = new SimpleScriptContext();
ctx.setBindings(engine.createBindings(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
engine.eval("function hello() { return 'Hello!'; }", ctx);
engine.setContext(ctx);

((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("hello");
```

Removing the `engine.setContext(ctx)` line would result in a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function hello` exception.

Depending on your situation, you may have to re-set the original context!